# updating substring(to:) results in generic parameter could not be inferred

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm using a framework that uses the `substring(to:)` which has now been deprecated in swift 4.

```
let split = stripped.substring(to: stripped.range(of: ";")?.lowerBound ?? stripped.endIndex)
```

I updated it to the code below, but now I get a 'generic parameter could not be inferred' error and the '..' is underlined.

```
let split = stripped[..<stripped.range(of: ";")?.lowerBound ?? stripped.endIndex]
```

Not sure how I'm suppose to fix this.

Comment: `let split = stripped[..<(stripped.range(of: ";")?.lowerBound ?? stripped.endIndex)]`

Comment: just add a parentheses englobing your upperBound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make this code clearer a bit:

```
let range = stripped.range(of: ";")?.lowerBound ?? stripped.endIndex
let split = String(stripped[..<range])
```

But it seems you want to get the substring before a certain character. I have another way to do that:

```
let split: String = stripped.components(separatedBy: ";").first!
```

Comment: Thanks! This isn't code I wrote myself and I'm having a hard time understanding whats going on. Would you be able to explain?

Comment: It gets the substring from the begin to the delimiter character ";", if there's no ";" in the string, get the whole string instead (get from begin to the end index)

Answer (score 0):

compiler cannot infer that your range starts *implicitly* from the `startIndex` of the `stripped`. You have to specify beginning of the range explicitly:

```
let split = stripped[stripped.startIndex..<(stripped.range(of: ";")?.lowerBound ?? stripped.endIndex)]
```

Actually, this is very hard to read, so consider writing *a bit* cleaner code:

```
let endIndex = stripped.range(of: ";")?.lowerBound ?? stripped.endIndex
let split = stripped[stripped.startIndex..<endIndex]
```